# GLSL built-in dFdx function not recognized

Tags: graphics, 3d, three.js, webgl, shader

I am writing shaders in GLSL. These tho shaders: (vertex shader and fragment shader) are for flat shading, but my problem is:

It did not work, so I tried to debug it somehow. When everything is commented, it works well, but, when I uncomment first line `vec3 u = dFdx(vVertex);`, it stops to work.

So my assumption is that it does not understand `dFdx()` function. In other functions (like `pow()`) the situation is similar.

Don't I have any library imported, or what can be other problems?

I use THREE.js and insert shaders into application.

```
<script type="text/x-glsl" id="flatVertexShader">
varying vec3 vVertex;

void main(){
    vVertex = vec3(modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0));
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}   

</script>

<script type="text/x-glsl" id="flatFragmentShader">
varying vec3 vVertex;

uniform int ill_type;           //type of illumination
uniform vec3 uMaterialColor;    //color of material
uniform float uKa;              //ambient coefficient [0,1]
uniform float uKd;              //diffuse coefficient [0,1]
uniform float uKs;              //specular coefficient [0,1]
uniform float uNShiny;          //shininess coefficient
uniform vec3 uDirLightPos;      //light position
uniform float uLightIntensity;  //light intensity [0,1]

void main()
{     
    vec3 u = dFdx(vVertex);
    //vec3 v = dFdy(vVertex);
    //vec3 u = vVertex;
    //vec3 v = vVertex;
    //vec3 N = normalize(cross(u,v));

    //ambient
    float ambient = uKa;
    float diffuse = 0.0;
    float specular = 0.0;


    //vec3 L = normalize(uDirLightPos - vVertex);

    //diffuse
    //diffuse += uLightIntensity * uKd * max(dot(N, L), 0.0);


    if(ill_type == 0){  //Phong Illumination Model
        //vec3 R = normalize(reflect(L,N));
        //specular += uLightIntensity * uKs * pow(max(dot(R,normalize(vVertex)),0.0), uNShiny);
    }
    else{               //Blinn Illumination Model
        //vec3 H = L-vVector;
        //H = H / length(H);
        //specular += uKs * uLightIntensity * pow(max(dot(N,H),0.0), uNShiny);
    }


    float total = ambient + diffuse + specular;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(total * uMaterialColor.x, total*uMaterialColor.y, total * uMaterialColor.z,1.0);
}
```

Comment: What is "stops working" supposed to mean?

Comment: In vanilla WebGL you'd need to have an extension directive in the beginning of your shader code to make use of derivative functions `#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable` I don't know whether these are automagically injected in three.js or not. WebGL provides [`getShaderInfoLog`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getShaderInfoLog) and [`getProgramInfoLog`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getProgramInfoLog) to debug shaders.